# Calculate Marker In Circle

Tags: google-maps-api-3

Base on this http://jsfiddle.net/kaiser/wzcst/light/ example, but the marker in circle is not accurate, when the marker is outside circle and near to circle it is consider inside the circle which is not wanted.

Is there any other idea?

**code snippet** (from linked fiddle):

```js
window.onload = function init() {
  var
    contentCenter = '<span class="infowin">Center Marker (draggable)</span>',
    contentA = '<span class="infowin">Marker A (draggable)</span>',
    contentB = '<span class="infowin">Marker B (draggable)</span>';
  var
    latLngCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(37.081476, -94.510574),
    latLngCMarker = new google.maps.LatLng(37.0814, -94.5105),
    latLngA = new google.maps.LatLng(37.2, -94.1),
    latLngB = new google.maps.LatLng(38, -93),
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 7,
      center: latLngCenter,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      mapTypeControl: false
    }),
    markerCenter = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: latLngCMarker,
      title: 'Location',
      map: map,
      draggable: true
    }),
    infoCenter = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: contentCenter
    }),
    markerA = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: latLngA,
      title: 'Location',
      map: map,
      draggable: true
    }),
    infoA = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: contentA
    }),
    markerB = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: latLngB,
      title: 'Location',
      map: map,
      draggable: true
    }),
    infoB = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: contentB
    })
    // exemplary setup: 
    // Assumes that your map is signed to the var "map"
    // Also assumes that your marker is named "marker"
    ,
    circle = new google.maps.Circle({
      map: map,
      clickable: false,
      // metres
      radius: 100000,
      fillColor: '#fff',
      fillOpacity: .6,
      strokeColor: '#313131',
      strokeOpacity: .4,
      strokeWeight: .8
    });
  // attach circle to marker
  circle.bindTo('center', markerCenter, 'position');

  var
  // get the Bounds of the circle
    bounds = circle.getBounds()
    // Note spans
    ,
    noteA = jQuery('.bool#a'),
    noteB = jQuery('.bool#b');

  noteA.text(bounds.contains(latLngA));
  noteB.text(bounds.contains(latLngB));

  // get some latLng object and Question if it's contained in the circle:
  google.maps.event.addListener(markerCenter, 'dragend', function() {
    latLngCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(markerCenter.position.lat(), markerCenter.position.lng());
    bounds = circle.getBounds();
    noteA.text(bounds.contains(latLngA));
    noteB.text(bounds.contains(latLngB));
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(markerA, 'dragend', function() {
    latLngA = new google.maps.LatLng(markerA.position.lat(), markerA.position.lng());
    noteA.text(bounds.contains(latLngA));
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(markerB, 'dragend', function() {
    latLngB = new google.maps.LatLng(markerB.position.lat(), markerB.position.lng());
    noteB.text(bounds.contains(latLngB));
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(markerCenter, 'click', function() {
    infoCenter.open(map, markerCenter);
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(markerA, 'click', function() {
    infoA.open(map, markerA);
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(markerB, 'click', function() {
    infoB.open(map, markerB);
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(markerCenter, 'drag', function() {
    infoCenter.close();
    noteA.html("draggin&hellip;");
    noteB.html("draggin&hellip;");
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(markerA, 'drag', function() {
    infoA.close();
    noteA.html("draggin&hellip;");
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(markerB, 'drag', function() {
    infoB.close();
    noteB.html("draggin&hellip;");
  });
};
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: .9em;
  color: #fff;
}
#note {
  text-align: center;
  padding: .3em;
  10px;
  background: #009ee0;
}
.bool {
  font-style: italic;
  color: #313131;
}
.info {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40%;
  text-align: center;
}
.infowin {
  color: #313131;
}
#title,
.bool {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="note"><span id="title">&raquo;Inside the circle?&laquo;</span>
  <hr /><span class="info">Marker <strong>A</strong>: <span id="a" class="bool"></span></span>&larr;&diams;&rarr; <span class="info">Marker <strong>B</strong>: <span id="b" class="bool"></span></span>
</div>
<div id="map">test</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A google.maps.LatLngBounds is a rectangle.  You need a polygon "contains" function.  For a circle this can be reduced to testing whether the point is less than the radius away from the center.

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/yGgcX/9/)

**code snippet:**

```js
window.onload = function init() {
  var
    contentCenter = '<span class="infowin">Center Marker (draggable)</span>',
    contentA = '<span class="infowin">Marker A (draggable)</span>',
    contentB = '<span class="infowin">Marker B (draggable)</span>';
  var
    latLngCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(37.081476, -94.510574),
    latLngCMarker = new google.maps.LatLng(37.0814, -94.5105),
    latLngA = new google.maps.LatLng(37.2, -94.1),
    latLngB = new google.maps.LatLng(38, -93),
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 7,
      center: latLngCenter,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      mapTypeControl: false
    }),
    markerCenter = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: latLngCMarker,
      title: 'Center of Circle',
      map: map,
      draggable: true
    }),
    infoCenter = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: contentCenter
    }),
    markerA = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: latLngA,
      title: 'A',
      map: map,
      label: "A",
      draggable: true
    }),
    infoA = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: contentA
    }),
    markerB = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: latLngB,
      title: 'B',
      map: map,
      label: "B",
      draggable: true
    }),
    infoB = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: contentB
    })
    // exemplary setup: 
    // Assumes that your map is signed to the var "map"
    // Also assumes that your marker is named "marker"
    ,
    circle = new google.maps.Circle({
      map: map,
      clickable: false,
      // metres
      radius: 100000,
      fillColor: '#fff',
      fillOpacity: .6,
      strokeColor: '#313131',
      strokeOpacity: .4,
      strokeWeight: .8
    });
  // attach circle to marker
  circle.bindTo('center', markerCenter, 'position');

  var
  // get the Bounds of the circle
    bounds = circle.getBounds()
    // Note spans
    ,
    noteA = jQuery('.bool#a'),
    noteB = jQuery('.bool#b');

  noteA.text((100000 > google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(markerA.getPosition(), markerCenter.getPosition())));
  noteB.text((100000 > google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(markerB.getPosition(), markerCenter.getPosition())));

  // get some latLng object and Question if it's contained in the circle:
  google.maps.event.addListener(markerCenter, 'dragend', function() {
    latLngCenter = markerCenter.position;
    noteA.text((100000 > google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(markerA.getPosition(), markerCenter.getPosition())));
    noteB.text((100000 > google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(markerB.getPosition(), markerCenter.getPosition())));
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(markerA, 'dragend', function() {
    latLngA = markerA.position;
    noteA.text((100000 > google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(markerA.getPosition(), markerCenter.getPosition())));
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(markerB, 'dragend', function() {
    latLngB = markerB.position;
    noteB.text((100000 > google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(markerB.getPosition(), markerCenter.getPosition())));
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(markerCenter, 'click', function() {
    infoCenter.open(map, markerCenter);
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(markerA, 'click', function() {
    infoA.open(map, markerA);
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(markerB, 'click', function() {
    infoB.open(map, markerB);
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(markerCenter, 'drag', function() {
    infoCenter.close();
    noteA.html("draggin&hellip;");
    noteB.html("draggin&hellip;");
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(markerA, 'drag', function() {
    infoA.close();
    noteA.html("draggin&hellip;");
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(markerB, 'drag', function() {
    infoB.close();
    noteB.html("draggin&hellip;");
  });
};
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: .9em;
  color: #fff;
}
#note {
  text-align: center;
  padding: .3em;
  10px;
  background: #009ee0;
}
.bool {
  font-style: italic;
  color: #313131;
}
.info {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40%;
  text-align: center;
}
.infowin {
  color: #313131;
}
#title,
.bool {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry&key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<div id="note"><span id="title">&raquo;Inside the circle?&laquo;</span>
  <hr /><span class="info">Marker <strong>A</strong>: <span id="a" class="bool"></span></span>&larr;&diams;&rarr; <span class="info">Marker <strong>B</strong>: <span id="b" class="bool"></span></span>
</div>
<div id="map">test</div>
```