# How to check if center of the map is within circle area after user will drag the map?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am having the map with marker in the middle of the screen.
I am also having the circle with boundaries of the "allowed" area for user to drag map's center within.
I need to show error message if user dragged the map outside of this circle.
Can you tell me what I am doing wrong in the code below?

I am having the error in this line: `if (_latLngBounds.contains(event.latLng))` because `event` does not have `latLng` param. I dont know how to get lat and lng of the current position properly.

```js
var map;

function initialize() {

  var _latitudeLongitude = new window.google.maps.LatLng(51.805616, -0.192647);

  var circle = new window.google.maps.Circle({
      center: _latitudeLongitude,
      radius: 50000
  });

  var _latLngBounds = circle.getBounds();

  var locations = [
    ['WELWYN GARDEN CITY&nbsp;', 51.805616, -0.192647, 2],
    ['STANMORE &nbsp;', 51.603199, -0.296803, 1]
  ];

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
    navigationControl: true,
    scrollwheel: false,
    scaleControl: false,
    draggable: true,
    zoom: 10,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.75339, -0.210114),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });

  var marker, i;

  for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
      map: map,
      zIndex: 10
    });

    window.google.maps.event.addListener(map , 'drag', function (event) {
            marker.setPosition( map.getCenter() );

            if (_latLngBounds.contains(event.latLng)) {
                // everything is fine
            } else {
                alert('outside of the boundaries');
            }

    });

  }
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map), the drag event doesn't have any arguments (also the dragend event).

> **Events**
>
> **drag** | Arguments:  None | This event is repeatedly fired while the user drags the map.

You would need to get the center of the map (by calling `map.getCenter()`).

```
window.google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'drag', function() {
  marker.setPosition(map.getCenter());

  if (_latLngBounds.contains(map.getCenter())) {
    // everything is fine
  } else {
    alert('outside of the boundaries');
  }

});
```

**Note:** A LatLngBounds is rectangular.  If you want to check for inside a circle, it won't be accurate (the corners of the rectangle aren't "in" the circle, but are in the bounds), check instead for distance to the point from the center of the circle is less than the radius of the circle.  See [Calculate Marker In Circle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11968316/calculate-marker-in-circle)

**code snippet:**

```js
var map;

function initialize() {

  var _latitudeLongitude = new window.google.maps.LatLng(51.805616, -0.192647);

  var circle = new window.google.maps.Circle({
    center: _latitudeLongitude,
    radius: 50000
  });

  var _latLngBounds = circle.getBounds();

  var locations = [
    ['WELWYN GARDEN CITY&nbsp;', 51.805616, -0.192647, 2],
    ['STANMORE &nbsp;', 51.603199, -0.296803, 1]
  ];

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
    navigationControl: true,
    scrollwheel: false,
    scaleControl: false,
    draggable: true,
    zoom: 10,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.75339, -0.210114),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });

  var marker, i;

  for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
      map: map,
      zIndex: 10
    });

    window.google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'drag', function() {
      marker.setPosition(map.getCenter());

      if (_latLngBounds.contains(map.getCenter())) {
        // everything is fine
      } else {
        alert('outside of the boundaries');
      }

    });
  }
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```